# is it possible to read the column name of a cell in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datagrid

I want to find the column name of the cell in the below event of a datagridview.

```
protected void grvDetailedStatus_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i <= e.Item.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        System.DateTime cellDate = default(System.DateTime);
        if (System.DateTime.TryParse(e.Item.Cells[i].Text, out cellDate))
        {
            e.Item.Cells[i].Text = string.Format("{0:d}", cellDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to find the column name of the cell I am manipulating?

EDIT:  Sorry for not giving a clear explanation. Let me explain it more clearly.

I want to do the below formatting only for particular column values:

```
protected void grvDetailedStatus_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= e.Item.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        System.DateTime cellDate = default(System.DateTime);
        if (System.DateTime.TryParse(e.Item.Cells[i].Text, out cellDate))
        {
            e.Item.Cells[i].Text = string.Format("{0:d}", cellDate);

        }
    }
}
```

Say, for example, I have to change the format of the date only for the "column1" and "column5". So now I want to know the column name and with that I want to format that column alone and leave the rest.

```
protected void grvDetailedStatus_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ( columnName == "Column1")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= e.Item.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            System.DateTime cellDate = default(System.DateTime);
            if (System.DateTime.TryParse(e.Item.Cells[i].Text, out cellDate))
            {
                e.Item.Cells[i].Text = string.Format("{0:d}", cellDate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

Comment: Your mentioning datagridview is confusing people. There are two flavors: DataGrid and GridView. You're using a DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're using a DataGrid. GridView is a similar control, but slightly different flavor. I'll also assume you're using autogenerated columns, in which case the `DataGrid.Columns` collection won't help you.

Instead of checking the column names each time, it's better to store the indexes of the columns you're interested in once. Like this:

```
private List<int> _myColumns;

protected void grvDetailedStatus_ItemDataBound(object sender,
    DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
    {
        _myColumns = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < _columnNames.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (e.Item.Cells[i].Text)
            {
                case "column1":
                case "column5":
                    // Interesting column, store index
                    _myColumns.Add(i);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        foreach (int i in _myColumns)
        {
            // Your original code:
            System.DateTime cellDate = default(System.DateTime);
            if (System.DateTime.TryParse(e.Item.Cells[i].Text, out cellDate))
            {
                e.Item.Cells[i].Text = string.Format("{0:d}", cellDate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to store all the column names, it would be fairly easy to adapt this code (or look at an earlier version of this post).

Comment: Care to comment on the downvote? This does exactly what he asked for?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd wager that you got it because he asked about GridViews. You edited his post to include a tag for DataGrid, and answered in context of that.

Comment: But he **is** using a DataGrid. GridView has no ItemDataBound event, and *doesn't* use `DataGridItemEventArgs`. Don't blame me for being observant :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running through the individual cells during the ItemDataBound event and need to get the column name of a cell then you can use the following:

```
protected void myDataGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    string colName;

    foreach (TableCell cell in e.Item.Cells)
    {
        //string cellTxt = e.Item.Cells[i].Text;
        DataRowView dv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        colName = dv.DataView.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to check whether the e.Item is an `ListItemType.Item` or `ListItemType.AlternatingItem` or `ListItemType.Header`. If it's a Header, then you can get the title as follows:

```
protected void grvDetailedStatus_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{ 
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header))
    {
        // retrieve the header text... e.g.
        string FirstCellHeader = e.Item.Cells[0].Text;
    }
    else if((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || 
         (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        // your code for items
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry i have updated the question more clearly.Please help.